# How do I add Voice Recognition to Nao Bot

Tags: python, voice-recognition, nao-robot

I need some help in voice recognition on the nao robot. In my code I start the engine, but I don't know how to add voice to memory then call it.
Any help is great. BTW this is in a class.

Here Is My Code:

```
    n = "WordRecognized"
    asr = self.session.service("ALSpeechRecognition")
    asr.pause(True)
    alm = self.session.service("ALMemory")
    alm.declareEvent(n)
    asr.setAudioExpression(True)
    asr.subscribe(n)
    self.say("Started Voice Recognition")
    time.sleep(t)
    asr.unsubscribe(n)
    print(alm.getData(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understand your question, but in general I recognize the issues with getting speech detection to work.
I see a single sleep, which is probably where it goes wrong.

You might need to do something like the following:

```
import time
# get current time as start time
t_start = time.time() 
t_current = t_start                              
RecognizedWords = []                    
duration = 10                           # detecting time

# if duration time has not passed
while t_current-t_start<duration:
    recognized_words = alm.getData(n)  
    # if something is in the list (thus something was detected)
    if len(recognized_words) > 0:          
        # then we break the loop, so we stop checking for more speech.
        break                       
    else:                               # if list is empty (nothing recognized)
        t_current = time.time()
```

Basically, it needs to constantly check for speech for a while, rather than sleep and see if anything was detected.
I believe this worked for me in the past anyway!

Hope this helps!